# Ember.js 0.9.5 not updating when using view helper

Tags: ember.js

In version `0.9.3` of Ember.js, I could do something like this:

```
Item = Ember.Object.Extend({
  title: 'A cool item',
  subview: Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'views_items_show'
  })
});

var item = Item.create(jsonData);

var itemIndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'views_items_index',
  item: item
});

itemIndexView.appendTo('body');
```

Then, in my `itemIndexView` view template:

```
<div class="some-class">
  <p>{{item.title}}</p>
  <div>
    {{view item.subview}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, if I update `itemIndexView`:

```
itemIndexView.set('item', newItem);
```

In Ember 0.9.3 `{{view item.subview}}` is updated automatically with the new view. This doesn't work in 0.9.5. Is there a different way to do this now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `Ember.ContainerView` when dealing with dynamic content.

Here is a working sample, refactored from your code: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/d6JD8/1/

Comment: +1. Only 2 things very small things I'd change/note with the code is you should use `getPath` instead of the 2 back-to-back `get` calls and `Ember.run.later` instead of `setTimeout`.

Comment: You are an amazing person. Thanks Mike and Roy!

Comment: @RoyDaniels: took remarks into account & updated the sample. Thanks!